# APNS push not arriving despite server reporting 200

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin.forms, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to implement push notifictions on my iOS app (which is a Xamarin forms project). I was using the excellent dotAPNS .net library on the server side and was able to compose a APNS request easily (using JWT authentication as is suggested in the Apple docs).

The APNS server returns 200/OK but I never receive anything on my device. Things look right, though; if I tamper with the device token I got from my iPhone (by changing the last digit for example), APNS returns 400/BadDeviceToken, which is perfectly correct. Also if I do things wrong with the composition of the JWT authentication, the server will correctly report an error.

But all I get is 200/OK, which should mean the push was delivered correctly (says the documentation).

Has anybody an idea, what's happening here?

Comment: Check this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67302562/ios-apns-push-notification-send-successfully-but-notification-not-receiving-in), it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me by setting WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE to 1 in the Azure App Service Configuration.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68913031/9372032